# How to change bar color (Google Chart Visualization)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am having trouble changing this columns charts color. Right now it is showing the default blue and not the cyan.

Here it is live: http://leighmckenzie.com/ballet-analysis/#when

```
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day of the Week', 'Number of Orders'],
      ["Monday", 5458],
      ["Tuesday", 4006],
      ["Wednesday", 3686],
      ["Thursday", 3675],
      ["Friday", 4006],
      ["Saturday", 3379],
      ["Sunday", 3395],

    ]);

    var options = {
      series: { 0: {color: '#00ada2'} },
      width: 300,
      height: 380,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      bar: { groupWidth: "80%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('orders-during-week'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an array of colors which match the series array.

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day of the Week', 'Number of Orders'],
      ["Monday", 5458],
      ["Tuesday", 4006],
      ["Wednesday", 3686],
      ["Thursday", 3675],
      ["Friday", 4006],
      ["Saturday", 3379],
      ["Sunday", 3395],

    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 300,
      height: 380,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      bar: { groupWidth: "80%" },
      colors: ['#00ada2']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  };
```